# Forms in email (no data being sent to server)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, html-email

Im trying to put a simple "+" or "-" vote form into an email newsletter.

```
// yes button "+"
<form action="/email-opinions/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="GSC" name="strainName">
<input type="hidden" value="yesLike" name="strainLike">
<input type="image"  src="/images/vhc/yesLike.png" alt="I Like">
</form>

// no button "-"
 <form action="/email-opinions/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="GSC" name="strainName">
<input type="hidden" value="noLike" name="strainLike">
<input type="image"  src="/images/vhc/noLike.png" alt="I Like">
</form>
```

The form is processed by a wordpress page:

```
// form vars
$strainLike = $_POST['strainLike'];
$strainName = $_POST['strainName'];

 // wordpress loop
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
    $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
      setup_postdata( $post ); 


        // strain data
        $currentStrain = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'strainName', true );    

        if ($strainName == $currentStrain) {


        // set the vote scores

            // no vote          
            if ($strainLike == 'noLike') {
                // vote data
                $currentYes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'yesLike', true ); 
                $currentNo  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'noLike', true ); 
                $newVote = $currentNo + '1';
                update_post_meta($post->ID, 'noLike', $newVote);


            }

            // yes vote
            if ($strainLike == 'yesLike') {
                // vote data
                $currentNo  = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'noLike', true ); 
                $currentYes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'yesLike', true ); 
                $newVote = $currentYes + '1';
                update_post_meta($post->ID, 'yesLike', $newVote);


            }


        }

    endforeach; ?>
```

It works fine as a web page. The form does what its supposed to do, But when emailed and you click on a form option, the resulting yes or no vote is not processed and counted or displayed back to the voter. anybody got an idea whats wrong?

Comment: Just give the recipient two links to click. Then in your processing script, get the values from the URL using something like `$_GET['blah']`

Answer (score 0):

Forms usually not allowed in html emails, of course there are a few exceptions. That kind of features can work with regular links (as henrywright mentioned in the comment above). Links are basic elements of html emails, and also much easier to track clicks.

Change the 2 forms to 2 links, 2 different urls, or the same url with different params.